# How do I get specific data from a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am having problems getting JSON data from an array.

I tried to print array data, but it's not working:

```
<div id='asd'>lalala</div>
<button onclick='myfunction()'>click me</button>

<script>
    function myfunction(){
        var arr = [];
        fetch('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-sv/blocks?a=month,median(transaction_count)')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => arr.push(result));
        console.log(arr)
        document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = arr[0]
    }
</script>
```

I get *"undefined error"*.

Comment: post your json data here

Comment: We'll need your JSON to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that:

```
console.log(arr)
document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML=arr[0];
```

Is outside your final `.then`, meaning that is will run when your code is first executed, not after your method has received its result. Instead, you need to put this in your final `.then` callback so that it first populates your array and then it outputs the result:

```
function myfunction(){
    var arr = [];
    fetch('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-sv/blocks?a=month,median(transaction_count)')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        arr.push(result);
        console.log(arr);
        document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr[0]);
    });    
}
```

Also, if you are adding the output to the DOM, you need to `.stringify` it so that the data can be display properly.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to fix yor callback function and also your array object exists in data. Please refer to following snippet.

```html
<div id='asd'>lalala</div>
<button onclick='myfunction()'>click me</button>
<script>
function myfunction(){
  var arr = [];
  fetch('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-sv/blocks?a=month,median(transaction_count)')
  .then(function(response) {
       return response.json();
  }).then(function(myJson) {
    arr.push(JSON.stringify(myJson.data));
    document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML=arr[0];
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using fetch to reach out to the server and that is an **asynchronous** operation as you need to wait for the response from the server in the `then` function.

You need to log the array inside the `then` function.

So it should be:

```
  function myfunction(){
     var arr = [];
     fetch('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-sv/blocks?a=month,median(transaction_count)')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(result => {
         arr.push(result)
         console.log(arr)
         document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML=arr[0]
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```js
function myfunction() {
  fetch('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-sv/blocks?a=month,median(transaction_count)')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(theJson => {
      const arr = theJson.data
      document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr[0])
    })
}
```

```html
<div id='asd'>lalala</div>
<button onclick='myfunction()'>click me</button>
```